# Implementing Iterator got error with throwing exceptions

Tags: java, exception, stack, binary-search-tree

This is part of my homework, since I couldn't figure it out I thought I would try asking on here.

I'm trying to implement an iterator on a BST using a stack. I got it compiled and running correctly, and the result seemed to be correct as well.

However, when I tried to use my school's auto-marker, it allows me to submit the code and the system will check using its model. I got the following error when it comes to running the iterator:

> !Analysis halted: Your code has produced an incorrect output, failed
>   to throw  an exception, or thrown an exception when it shouldn't have.
>
> java.lang.Exception: Your code has produced an incorrect output,
>   failed to throw  an exception, or thrown an exception when it
>   shouldn't have.   at LabProject.main(LabProject.java:115)

I'm pretty sure (as it says) that I'm having trouble with throwing the exceptions somewhere in the implementation below, or perhaps I missed throwing them at some points. I've checked several times and can't seem to get it right. Could anybody see what I need to do?

Here is the code:

```
public class DictionaryItr<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E> {

    private MyNode first; // top of stack
    public int modCount = 0;

    // helper linked list class
    private class MyNode {
        private E item;
        private MyNode next;
    }

    public DictionaryItr(DictionaryImp.DictNode root) {
        first = null;
        this.loadNodes(root);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void loadNodes(DictionaryImp.DictNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            loadNodes(node.right);
            this.push((E)node.value);
            loadNodes(node.left);
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void push(E item) {
        MyNode oldfirst = first;
        first = new MyNode();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
        modCount++;
    }

    public E pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Stack underflow");
        E item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        return item;
    }

    public E peek() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Stack underflow");
        return first.item;
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator();
    }

    private class ListIterator implements Iterator<E> {
        private MyNode current = first;
        private int expectedModCount;

        public ListIterator() {
            expectedModCount = modCount;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() { 
            return current != null;
        }

        public void remove() {
            current = current.next;
        }

        public E next() {
            if (modCount != expectedModCount) throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException("No more elements");
            else {
                E item = current.item;
                current = current.next;
                return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welp, I'm pretty sure your `remove()` implementation is supposed to actually modify the backing collection, not just the iterator.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it has nothing to do with the exceptions doesn't it? I tried to ignore its implementation but didn't work as well.

Comment: What can you do wrong with an iterator? Calling next without a hasNext first. Should peek throw an exception or return null?

Comment: Tried to return null but doesn't seem to solve either... hmm too much headache with this.

Comment: perhaps it belongs to the case "...failed to throw an exception" rather than "...or thrown an exception when it shouldn't have"

Answer (score 0):

The remove method must throw the exception `UnsupportedOperationException` if it is not implemented, or, and this is your case, if it is implemented, it will throw an `IllegalStateException` if you call the remove() method before calling next() at least once, or if you have no element to remove (current attribute is null). You can see the detail here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Besides, the remove() method will throw a `NullPointerException` if called after the last the next() method invokation (hasNext() == false), and, as said before, it must throw a `IllegalStateException`

I think these are the problems you're having.